# What happens to Contract.Requires when built without Code Contracts installed?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

In our project, we define two three build configurations, Release, Debug and 'Debug-plus-contracts'. These are defined as below:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug-plus-contracts'">
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;CONTRACTS_FULL</DefineConstants>
  <CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>True</CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>
  <CodeContractsRuntimeThrowOnFailure>False</CodeContractsRuntimeThrowOnFailure>
  ...
```

We define two debug configurations because 'Debug-plus-contracts' only builds on machines with [Code Contracts for .NET](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) installed

My question is, what happens to a line such as `Contract.Requires(source.Any())` when it's compiled in each configuration? Suppose it's violated at runtime, in which configurations will anything happen?

---

I ask because I heard (somewhere) that in the Debug configuration, `Contract.Requires` is compiled to `Debug.Assert` . But evidence suggests this isn't true, we have some `Contract.Requires` that fail in Debug-plus but not in Debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Contract.Requires` is declared as

> ```
> [ConditionalAttribute("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
> public static void Requires(
>   bool condition
> )
>
> [ConditionalAttribute("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
> public static void Requires(
>   bool condition,
>   string userMessage
> )
> ```

which means that if the `CONTRACTS_FULL` symbol is not defined, any call to `Requires` will be removed by the compiler completely. The check will not be performed at all.

If you do define the `CONTRACTS_FULL` symbol, but you don't have Code Contracts installed at build time or do not use its rewriter, any call to `Requires` will throw an exception regardless of whether the check passes, telling you that without the Code Contracts rewriter, it won't work.

Note: this is different from `Contract.Requires<TException>`. The latter does not have the same `ConditionalAttribute`, so will fail in any configuration unless the Code Contracts rewriter is used.

Comment: (+1) Note that the "you don't have Code Contracts installed" in this answer is referring to the BUILD machine. You of course DO NOT NEED Code Contracts installed on the customer's machine. Also note that generally you should choose assembly mode "Standard Contract Requires" rather than "Custom Parameter Validation" (which unfortunately appears to be the default).

Comment: @MatthewWatson You're completely correct, and I've edited my answer to hopefully be slightly clearer about that.